# Error: ( : 1) Invalid number of arguments for python-fu command line execution

Tags: python, gimp, python-fu, gimpfu

I have added the following python script to */usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins* folder

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from gimpfu import *

def scale(imageName):
    pass

register(
    "my",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "2017",
    "<Image>/Image/Hi..",
    "RGB*, GRAY*",
    [(PF_STRING, 'file_name', 'file_name', 'logo.png')],
    [],
    scale)

main()
```

Running it via

```
gimp --no-interface -b '(python-fu-my RUN-NONINTERACTIVE "logo.png")' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

returns

> batch command experienced an execution error: Error: ( : 1) Invalid
>   number of arguments for python-fu-my (expected 4 but
>   received 2)

In Gimp's Procedure Browser there are 4 parameters indeed, but it should not expect them if procedure is run via command line, should it?

[image: Parameters]

I followed the [docs](https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/).
What is wrong?

Comment: try temporarily changing `imageName` to `*imageName`, which will collect all the arguments provided to the function and wont complain if there are too many/few. Then you can print them out and see what is actually being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't register the function as a plugin, and you should call it directly (`scale("logo.png")`). But your code has to explicitly load the image file to obtain a gimp.Image object.

Comment: hi, if i run it directly i get *gimp_wire_write_msg: the wire protocol has not been initialized* error

Comment: "Running it directly" stll means using Gimp. Something like `gimp --no-interface -b '(scale logo.png")' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'`. You may have to tweak the python path and do an explicit import of your script: `gimp-idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b 'import sys; sys.path=["."]+sys.path;import yourscript;yourscript.run("logo.png")' -b 'pdb.gimp_quit(1)`